# Query on a variable that includes a specific range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may be slightly confusing so I'll try to be detailed. I need to query several months of daily records based on a certain variable. In this case a file name. There were several failed files that were rerun, and the rerun will include the original job run number in the new file name. For instance:

run 4145 failed. File name of `"ORIGINALFILENAME"`
run 4150 file name will look like `"YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_4145_ORIGINALFILENAME"`

There are 50+ failed files over the course of several months. Is there a way to build my where statement such that it will return both the failed runs (easily done via `status_code = 'FAILURE'`) as well as the reruns? I imagine something like `where file_name like '%_(select run_number where status_code = 'FAILURE')_ORIGINALFILENAME`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Sure this could be done. But we need some details in order to help. Things like column names and sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: note `_` in a like clause is *any single character* use `[_]` for the `_` character

Answer (score 0):

The % character will work for any or no characters. So

```
where file_name like '%ORIGINALFILENAME'
```

will work for the failures and the reruns

Answer (score 0):

This script return all the tuples which contain **status_code** = 'FAILURE' and where the **file_name** contains the sub-string "_ORIGINALFILENAME".

```
  SELECT file_name FROM tblYourTable
    WHERE status_code = 'FAILURE'
    AND file_name LIKE '%[_ORIGINALFILENAME]%'
```

but... on a second look the requirement seems to be: "***...statement such that it will return both the failed runs (easily done via status_code = 'FAILURE') as well as the reruns...***" which if I understand correctly implies to adjust the predicate to return **either** scenario i.e.:

```
  SELECT file_name FROM tblYourTable
    WHERE status_code = 'FAILURE'
    OR file_name LIKE '%[_ORIGINALFILENAME]%'
```

Comment: While potentially correct, it'd be nice if the answer included an explanation as to why it solves the problem.